# Reactive Extensions: Split input, process, and concatenate back

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Basically, I have an observable of input strings that I want to process individually and then do something with the result. If the input string contains commas (as a delimiter), I want to split the string and process each substring individually and then do something with the each sequence of strings. The snippet below illustrates a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
[Fact]
public void UniTest1()
{
    var observable = new ReplaySubject<string>();
    observable.OnNext("a,b");
    observable.OnNext("c,d,e");
    observable.OnCompleted();

    var result = new List<string[]>();
    observable
        .SelectMany(x => x.Split(','))
        .Select(x => x.ToUpper())
        .ToArray() // How to collect an IEnumerable for each item here?
        .Do(s => result.Add(s))
        .Subscribe();

    // Here, result is actually {{"A","B","C","D","E"}}, I need {{"A","B"},{"C","D","E"}}
    Assert.Equal(2, result.Count);

    Assert.Equal("A", result[0][0]);
    Assert.Equal("B", result[0][1]);

    Assert.Equal("C", result[1][0]);
    Assert.Equal("D", result[1][1]);
    Assert.Equal("E", result[1][2]);
}
```

As explained in the comment, the above does NOT work. The .ToArray()-call concatenates the entire observable into a single sequence.

However, I have solved this by putting the splitting and processing into a single action, as such:

```
[Fact]
public void UniTest2()
{
    var observable = new ReplaySubject<string>();
    observable.OnNext("a,b");
    observable.OnNext("c,d,e");
    observable.OnCompleted();

    var result = new List<string[]>();
    observable
        .Select(x => x.Split(',').Select(s => s.ToUpper()).ToArray())
        .Do(s => result.Add(s))
        .Subscribe();

    // Result is as expected: {{"A","B"},{"C","D","E"}}
    Assert.Equal(2, result.Count);
    Assert.Equal("A", result[0][0]);
    Assert.Equal("B", result[0][1]);
    Assert.Equal("C", result[1][0]);
    Assert.Equal("D", result[1][1]);
    Assert.Equal("E", result[1][2]);
}
```

But is there a way, using Rx, to solve this problem by NOT putting the splitting and processing in the same action? What is the recommended solution for this problem?

I should also mention that the processing, i.e. the ToUpper()-call, is in reality a web-service call. I used ToUpper() in my examples so that my problem should be easy to explain. But that means I want this processing to be done in parallel and non-blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things that you've ended up raising in you code that are worth mentioning.

To start with, the `.ToArray()` operator takes an observable that returns zero or more single values and changes it to an observable that returns a single array of zero or more values. Such an observable must complete before it can return its one and only value.

With this in mind the results of the first query should make sense.

Your second query with the `x.Split(',').Select(s => s.ToUpper()).ToArray()` produces the output that you wanted, but you wanted to know "is there a way, using RX, to solve this problem by NOT putting the splitting and processing in the same action".

Well, trivially, yes:

```
var result = new List<string[]>();
observable
    .Select(x => x.Split(','))
    .Select(x => x.Select(s => s.ToUpper()))
    .Select(x => x.ToArray())
    .Do(s => result.Add(s))
    .Subscribe();
```

However, this doesn't process the items in parallel. Rx is designed to work in series unless you invoke an operation that introduces parallelism.

Often, an easy way to do that is to take a long-running select, such as `.Select(x => longRunningOperation(x))` and do this with it:

```
.SelectMany(x => Observable.Start(() => longRunningOperation(x)))
```

In your case you could begin by doing this:

```
observable
    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
    .SelectMany(x => Observable.Start(() => x.Split(',')))
    .SelectMany(x => Observable.Start(() => x.Select(s => s.ToUpper())))
    .SelectMany(x => Observable.Start(() => x.ToArray()))
    .Do(s => result.Add(s))
    .Subscribe();
```

But that is only parallelizing each original `.OnNext` call, not the processing within. To do that you need to turn the result of the `x.Split(',')` into an observable, and process that in parallel.

```
    observable
        .SelectMany(x => Observable.Start(() => x.Split(',').ToObservable()))
        .SelectMany(x => Observable.Start(() => x.SelectMany(s => Observable.Start(() => s.ToUpper()))))
        .SelectMany(x => Observable.Start(() => x.ToArray()))
        .Do(s => s.Do(t => result.Add(t)))
        .Merge()
        .Subscribe();
```

But that's starting to look crazy and it no longer runs on the current thread, meaning that your test isn't going to wait for the results.

Let's relook at this query.

I've begun by getting rid of the `.Do` call. These are generally good for debugging, but for any state changes they are bad. They can run at any point on any thread within a query so you need to make sure that your code in a `.Do` call is thread-safe and calling `result.Add(s)` is **NOT** thread-safe.

I've also introduced a "webservice" call to replace `.ToUpper()` with a one second processing delay so that we can see how long the query takes to process and thus know if it is running in parallel or not. If the final query takes 5 seconds to run then no parallism and if it's less then we're winning.

So, if I write the query in the most basic way it looks like this:

```
Func<string, string> webservice = x =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return x.ToUpper();
};

var query =
    observable
        .Select(ls =>
            from p in ls.Split(',')
            select webservice(p))
        .Select(rs => rs.ToArray())
        .ToArray()
        .Select(rss => new List<string[]>(rss));

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
List<string[]> result = query.Wait();
sw.Stop();
```

When I run this I get the results as expected `{{"A","B"},{"C","D","E"}}`, but it takes just over 5 seconds to complete. No parallelism here as expected.

Let's now introduce some parallelism:

```
var query =
    observable
        .Select(ls =>
            from p in ls.Split(',').ToObservable()
            from r in Observable.Start(() => webservice(p))
            select r)
        .Select(rs => rs.ToArray())
        .Merge()
        .ToArray()
        .Select(rss => new List<string[]>(rss));
```

I've basically applied the "`Select` to `SelectMany`/`Start`" pattern that I described above. The only tricky part was that the `.Select(rs => rs.ToArray())` went from being an `IObservable<string[]>` to a `IObservable<IObservable<string[]>>` so I popped in the `.Merge()` to flatten it back out. This is normal when you introduce parallelism into Rx queries.

Now when I run the query - BOOM - just over one second. All five of the inputs are running in parallel. The only problem now is that the order is no longer determinant. But you can't help that when the results are performed in parallel.

One such run I got this result:

[image: results]

If I were running this as a test I would sort the results into a known order and compare that to the expected result.

Comment: If you want to retain the order you can use `Select(...).Concat()` instead of `SelectMany(...)`.

Comment: @Dorus - Then you lose the parallel processing.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The essence was the parallel processing. I could probably have been more clear about that. Also, the order of the output is actually not important in this case.

Comment: Nope, you'll keep parallel.

Comment: @Dorus - No, `.Concat` waits for the the first observable complete before even subscribing to the second one. You most certainly do lose parallel processing. Try doing `Observable.Never<int>().Concat(Observable.Return(1))` - you never get a value, but replace `Concat` with `Merge` and you do.

Comment: Mmm i'm clueless, when i tried this yesterday parallelism was kept with `Concat`. But now i cant get it to work... I'm confused. Anyway you are right `Concat` with `Observable.Never` wont complete, but that is just because it keeps waiting for `Never` to finish. I was talking about cases where the first Observer does finish. Seems that doesn't work either.

Comment: Also ran  my code from my own answer again. It does seem to work there. I need to dig into this later.

Comment: @Dorus - I ran your code - I put in mine - and it definitely ran in series. The five 1 second operations took 5 seconds in total.

Comment: Yup same here, i now cant figure out what i did different before. Removed the whole idea for now :/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to keep the original arrays. However, after `SelectMany`, you have flattened the arrays into single values directly on the stream, so you can no longer change them back into individual arrays. The trick is to move `ToUpper` and `ToArray` inside the `SelectMany`.

Also `ToUpper` is not an async function. It is important it is, else you wont get any parallelism (I assume it is in your real code, but it makes `ToUpper` a poor substitute.). Instead I'm going to use `Observable.Timer`. If your web service call is not already an observable, you need to convert it, but that's a different question and a little out of scope here.

This does mean your results can potentially be out of order.

```
new string[] { "a,b", "c,d,e" }.ToObservable()
    .SelectMany(str => str.Split(',')
        .ToObservable()
        .SelectMany(x => Observable.Timer(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2))
            .Select(_ => x.ToUpper()))
        .ToArray())
    .Subscribe(arr => { Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", arr)); });
```

---

Some other things i noticed in your code:

```
    .Do(s => result.Add(s))
    .Subscribe();
```

You can put the `result.Add(s)` directly in `Subscribe`

```
    .Subscribe(s => result.Add(s));
```

In fact, if you are writing testcases, use a `testScheduler` and `results.Messages.AssertEqual`.

```
using Microsoft.Reactive.Testing;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTests : ReactiveTest
    {

        [Test]
        public void UniTest1()
        {
            var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();

            var source = new string[] { "a,b", "c,d,e" }.ToObservable();

            var results = testScheduler.Start(
                () => source.SelectMany(str => str.Split(',')
                    .ToObservable()
                    .Select(x => x.ToUpper())
                    .ToArray()));

            results.Messages.AssertEqual(
                OnNext<string[]>(Subscribed, new string[] { "A", "B" }),
                OnNext<string[]>(Subscribed, new string[] { "C", "D", "E" }),
                OnCompleted<string[]>(Subscribed)
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Useful resources on testing Rx:
http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html#TestingRx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/06/14/testing-rx-queries-using-virtual-time-scheduling.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242967%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: I tested your query `source.SelectMany(str => str.Split(',').ToObservable().Select(x => x.ToUpper()).ToArray())`. It's **not** running in parallel as the OP wants.

Comment: @Enigmativity Only because `ToUpper` is not an async function. Let me replace it with something that is.

Comment: Also, looking back, I actually think I missed the edit the OP made 10 hours ago, because it took me 3 hours to write this (I got distracted with other things). This question wasn't about parallelism before.

Comment: It doesn't need to be async. Rx has everything it needs to make any function async with `Observable.Start`.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, and various other options, depending on the usecase. With async i meant Rx async, since an `IObservable` doesn't have to be. TPL async functions are easy to convert too with `ToObservable()`.

Comment: It's best to avoid mixing Rx with TPL. You can lose Rx's deferred execution and also cause deadlocks if you're not careful. It's not a hard rule, but it is a solid guideline.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain - You're going to think I'm picking on you - but the query that starts with `new string[] { "aaa,bbb", "c,d,e" }` is of type `IObservable<IObservable<char>[]>` and you're subscribing to the outer observable, but not the inner ones so the actual calls to `x.ToUpper()` isn't made. It effectively completes instantly without doing any computation.

Comment: @Enigmativity Oops haha. No i appreciate it, i edited the wrong `Select` into `SelectMany` when removing the `Concat`. I really need to pay more attention to what post :)